# Performance during scoring complex match in Neo4j graph database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have Neo4j 3.3.5 graph database: 27GB, 50kk nodes, 500kk relations. Indexes on. [Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDzxa.png). PC: 16GB ram, 4 cores.

Task is to find best matching companies for given query data. 
Nodes :Company, which I need to get, have multiple relations with nodes:Branch's, :Country's, etc.
Query data has BranchIds, CountryIds, etc.

Currently I am using cypher like this to get score from one relations (500k rows in result):

```
MATCH (c:Company)-[r:HAS_BRANCH]->(b:Branch)
WHERE b.branchId in [27444, 1692, 23409, ...] //around 10 ids per query
RETURN 
c.companyId as Id, 
case r.branchType 
 when 0 then 25
 ... // //around 7 conditions per query 
 when 10 then 20 
end as Score
```

I have to score like this all relations types for :Company, group by `Id`, sum `Score`, order and take top 100 results.

Because of lack of post union processing, I am using `collect` + `unwind` in order to merge scores from all relations.

Unfortunately, the performance is low. I get response for query of one relations (like above) in 5-10 seconds. When I am trying to combine results with `collect` + `unwind`, the query "never" ends.

What is better/proper way to do it? Maybe I am doing something wrong with graph design? Hardware configuration to low? Or maybe there are some algorithms to match with score graph (query data) in graph database?

**UPDATE**

Query explanation:

User can search in our system for companies. For his query we prepare query data contains ids of branches, countries, words, etc. 
In result of query we want to get list of best matching companies ids with score.

E.g. user can search for new companies producing wooden tables from Spain.

Combined query example:

```
MATCH (c:Company)-[r:HAS_BRANCH]->(b:Branch)
WHERE b.branchId in ["27444" , "1692" , "23409" , "8744" , "9192" , "26591" , "21396" , "27151" , "20228" , "3517" , "25058" , "29549"] 
WITH case r.branchType 
when "0" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 25}) 
 when "1" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 19}) 
 when "2" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 20}) 
 when "3" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 19}) 
 when "4" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 20}) 
 when "5" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 15}) 
 when "6" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 6}) 
 when "7" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 5}) 
 when "8" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 4}) 
 when "9" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 4}) 
 when "10" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 20}) 
end as rows
MATCH (c:Company)-[r:HAS_REVERTED_BRANCH]->(b:Branch)
WHERE b.branchId in ["27444" , "1692" , "23409" , "8744" , "9192" , "26591" , "21396" , "27151" , "20228" , "3517" , "25058" , "29549"] 
WITH rows + case r.branchType 
when "0" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 25}) 
 when "1" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 19}) 
 when "2" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 20}) 
 when "3" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 19}) 
 when "10" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 20}) 
end as rows
MATCH (c:Company)-[r:HAS_COUNTRY]->(cou:Country)
WHERE cou.countryId in ["9580" , "18551" , "15895"] 
WITH rows + case r.branchType 
when "0" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 30}) 
 when "2" then collect({id:c.companyId, score: 15}) 
 end as rows
... //here I would add in future other relations scoring
UNWIND rows AS row
RETURN row.id AS Id, sum(row.score) AS Score
ORDER BY Score DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Can you share with is the explain of your query and the full query ?
Moreover it seems that the `HAS_BRANCH` relationship is important for your business, and generally if it's important, it should be a node.

Comment: @logisima thank you for your comment, I have updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query to see if it's better or not :

```
MATCH (c:Company) WITH c
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r1:HAS_BRANCH]->(b:Branch) WHERE b.branchId in ["27444" , "1692" , "23409" , "8744" , "9192" , "26591" , "21396" , "27151" , "20228" , "3517" , "25058" , "29549"] 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r2:HAS_REVERTED_BRANCH]->(c:Branch) WHERE c.branchId in ["27444" , "1692" , "23409" , "8744" , "9192" , "26591" , "21396" , "27151" , "20228" , "3517" , "25058" , "29549"] 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r3:HAS_COUNTRY]->(cou:Country) WHERE cou.countryId in ["9580" , "18551" , "15895"] 
WITH c, 
    case r1.branchType 
      when "0" then 25
      when "1" then 19 
      when "2" then 20 
      when "3" then 19 
      when "4" then 20 
      when "5" then 15 
      when "6" then 6 
      when "7" then 5 
      when "8" then 4 
      when "9" then 4 
      when "10" then 20 
    end as branchScore,
    case r2.branchType 
      when "0" then  25 
      when "1" then  19 
      when "2" then  20 
      when "3" then  19 
      when "10" then  20 
    end as revertedBranchScore,
    case r3.branchType 
      when "0" then  30
      when "2" then  15 
    end as countryScore

WITH c.id AS Id, branchScore + revertedBranchScore + countryScore AS Score
RETURN Id, sum(Score) AS Score
ORDER BY Score DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Or a better one will be this one (but only if a `Company` node is mandatory linked to to a `Country` and `Branch`) :

```
MATCH 
  (c:Company)-[r1:HAS_BRANCH]->(b:Branch),
  (c)-[r2:HAS_REVERTED_BRANCH]->(c:Branch),
  (c)-[r3:HAS_COUNTRY]->(cou:Country)
WHERE 
  b.branchId in ["27444" , "1692" , "23409" , "8744" , "9192" , "26591" , "21396" , "27151" , "20228" , "3517" , "25058" , "29549"] AND 
  c.branchId in ["27444" , "1692" , "23409" , "8744" , "9192" , "26591" , "21396" , "27151" , "20228" , "3517" , "25058" , "29549"] AND
  cou.countryId in ["9580" , "18551" , "15895"]
WITH c, 
    case r1.branchType 
      when "0" then 25
      when "1" then 19 
      when "2" then 20 
      when "3" then 19 
      when "4" then 20 
      when "5" then 15 
      when "6" then 6 
      when "7" then 5 
      when "8" then 4 
      when "9" then 4 
      when "10" then 20 
    end as branchScore,
    case r2.branchType 
      when "0" then  25 
      when "1" then  19 
      when "2" then  20 
      when "3" then  19 
      when "10" then  20 
    end as revertedBranchScore,
    case r3.branchType 
      when "0" then  30
      when "2" then  15 
    end as countryScore

WITH c.id AS Id, branchScore + revertedBranchScore + countryScore AS Score
RETURN Id, sum(Score) AS Score
ORDER BY Score DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I have tested first query (second unfortunately is not an option). Its perform better, I am able to get response from db (I have to add `else 0` to case statement). But it is still minutes to go. Do you think, it could perform better if I change shema to :Company-[:HAS]->:Branch-[:IS]->:BranchType ?

Comment: you are calculating a score on all the companies (ie 1.5M), so it's normal that it takes times, and you said that you can't filter them before to make the score ... Making your suggestion will help. An other solution is to use the second solution by adding some empty Node for `Country`, `Branch`, etc

Comment: I have tested second query, and as I thought it gives different result. It is matching companies which has at least one id in listed branchIds AND one in revertedBranchIds AND one in countriesIds (`where` clauses). I need OR. Empty node does not make a difference.  I am going to test changed schema now.

Comment: I am setting this as the answer, because the speed was the best.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if we can keep cardinality down from your matches by using pattern comprehension and the reduce() function to update the score per company as the query progresses, as well as wait until the end to project out the id property:

```
MATCH (c:Company)
WITH c, [(c)-[r:HAS_BRANCH]->(b:Branch) 
 WHERE b.branchId in ["27444" , "1692" , "23409" , "8744" , "9192" , "26591" , "21396" , "27151" , "20228" , "3517" , "25058" , "29549"] | r.branchType] as hasBranchTypes
WITH c, reduce(runningScore = 0, type in hasBranchTypes | runningScore + 
 case type 
 when "0" then 25
 when "1" then 19
 when "2" then 20 
 when "3" then 19 
 when "4" then 20 
 when "5" then 15 
 when "6" then 6 
 when "7" then 5 
 when "8" then 4 
 when "9" then 4 
 when "10" then 20 
 end ) as score

WITH c, score, [(c:Company)-[r:HAS_REVERTED_BRANCH]->(b:Branch)
 WHERE b.branchId in ["27444" , "1692" , "23409" , "8744" , "9192" , "26591" , "21396" , "27151" , "20228" , "3517" , "25058" , "29549"] | r.branchType] as revertedBranchTypes
WITH c, reduce(runningScore = score, type in revertedBranchTypes | runningScore + 
 case type
 when "0" then 25
 when "1" then 19 
 when "2" then 20 
 when "3" then 19 
 when "10" then 20 
end ) as score

WITH c, score, [(c:Company)-[r:HAS_COUNTRY]->(cou:Country)
 WHERE cou.countryId in ["9580" , "18551" , "15895"] | r.branchType] as hasCountryTypes
WITH c, reduce(runningScore = score, type in hasCountryTypes | runningScore + 
 case type
 when "0" then 30 
 when "2" then 15 
 end ) as score
 //here I would add in future other relations scoring

WITH c, score
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 100
RETURN c.id as Id, score as Score
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tested this approach and it is slower. I have to limit companies in first line with `WITH c LIMIT 100000` (~10%) in order to get any result in 6 times slower than query from 1 answer. [Query plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyizj.png).